# Game Maker - Check Collision With Subimages

Tags: mouse, collision-detection, game-maker

I have an `obj_roulette`, which contains 4 subimages, with `value 2-5` and `image_number 0-3`. The value result from roulette stored as var `global.roulette`.

Then, I make many `obj_meteorite`, which contains 4 subimages too, spawn from above with `random x value` and `random image_number`. Player can shoot them with left-mouse click.

This is what I want:

`If image_number obj_roulette is 0, and player shoot obj_meteorite with image_number 0, score +10.
If image_number obj_roulette is 0, and player shoot obj_meteorite with image_number 1, score -10.`

I don't know how to check collision between `mouse_x/mouse_y` and object `image_number`, and how to match `obj_roulette` `image_number` and `obj_meteorite` `image_number`.

Is it using collision checking? If it yes, then maybe the examples in these links can help:
[link 1](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/movement%20and%20collisions/collisions/position_meeting.html)
[link 2](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/movement%20and%20collisions/collisions/collision_point.html)

Please explain your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the kind of game where you click with your mouse and hit exactly where the mouse was clicked. And as I understand it from your question. If the mouse is clicked and obj_roulette's image_index is the same as obj_meteorite, you want to add 10 to the score. If not, you want to subtract 10 from the score. And you need help converting your pseudo-code into gml.

```
// Check if obj_meteorite was clicked
if (mouse_check_button_released(mb_left) && position_meeting(mouse_x, mouse_y, obj_meteorite))
{
    // Check wheter or not obj_meteorite's and obj_roulette's image_index is the same
    if (obj_meteorite.image_index == obj_roulette.image_index)
    {
        // Add 10 to the score
        score += 10;
    }
    else
    {
        // Subtract 10 from the score
        score -= 10;
    }
}
```

If this is not what you want, I suggest editing your question to make it more clear. Preferably explain shortly what your game is actually about.

Comment: I try your code, and change it a little bit.

`if(obj_meteorite.image_index == obj_roulette.image_index)`

But, the result is, the code doesn't check the mouse click. So, even if I just hover above a meteorite, the score is changed. And, the score value is minus.

Comment: Ah, just put in a mouse button check then. I edited the code above. And you wanted it to distract 10 if the image_index was 1?

Comment: First, where should I put your code? In obj_meteorite step event? Second, your code successfully checks the mouse clicks, but the score is still minus. And sometimes the score is reduced by random number, not always 10, but sometimes the score isn't changed. Third, you have a misunderstanding here. What I want is, if the image_index of roulette result is same with the clicked meteorite image_index, score +10, if it's different, score -10. That's why I changed your code last time